# Where is maildirmake?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

When I run maildirmake I get maildirmake: command not found. Where is it, and if it's not included in Ubuntu 11, how do I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu the command is maildirmake.dovecot. If you want to use the plain command maildirmake on Ubuntu, you have to install maildrop (aptitude install maildrop).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an email service installed on your system such as courier or dovecot? Look at this [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=maildirmake&mode=filename&suite=natty&arch=any). Actually `maildirmake` is a symlink to one of these packages `maildirmake` binary like `/usr/bin/maildirmake.courier`.

Comment: I do have dovecot and postfix installed. But how would I use maildirmake to make a mail directory in my root directory? All the tutorials I've seen online make it seem like you can just call maildirmake anywhere and it automagically creates the mail folder with the 3 directories in it. Or you call ls -l Maildir and it tells you everything you need to know. I can't do that on my Linux box. I'm so confused.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger: You can consider `maildirmake` like `mkdir` command. However, it will not create a single folder. Instead, it will create mail dir structure.

Comment: I know what it is, I just didn't know where to find it.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger: Did you try searching for it using `which`, `locate`, or `find`?